# Microphone Audio Streaming from ESP8266 to C# Socket Server over wifi

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, c#

I want to stream the audio recorded by microphone on my ESP8266MOD to my C# Socket Program using UDP packets. But I'm getting analog outputs on every second. If I try to convert that signal to .wav file in my C# program it says that: "The wave header is corrupt.". Anyone have solution for this?

This is my Code for C# server:

```
public class UDPAudioListner
{
    private const int listenPort = 12000;
    public static int Main()
    {
        bool done = false;
        UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
        listener.DontFragment = true;
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.145");
        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, listenPort);
        byte[] receive_byte_array;
        List<byte[]> masterByteList = new List<byte[]>();
        byte[] bt = new byte[512];

        int i = 44;
        try
        {
            while (!done)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for broadcast");
                receive_byte_array = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
                Console.WriteLine("Received a broadcast from {0}", groupEP.ToString());
                var data = "";
                if (receive_byte_array.Length > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (Stream s = new MemoryStream(receive_byte_array))
                        {
                            s.Position = 0;
                            System.Media.SoundPlayer myPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(s);
                            myPlayer.Stream = null;
                            myPlayer.Stream = s;
                            myPlayer.Play();
                            bt = new byte[512];
                            i = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        done = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        listener.Close();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here is my Arduino code:

```
void sendAudio(){
    IPAddress ip(255, 255, 255, 122);
    unsigned int localPort = 12000;
    UdpSA.beginPacket(ip, localPort);
    mic = analogRead(A0);
    analogWrite(3,mic>> 2);
    UdpSA.write(mic);
    UdpSA.endPacket();
}
```

Comment: Are you writing the value from an analog read into a WAV file and expecting the WAV file to play that one value?  I've never created a WAV file but I would have thought you would need a frequency and duration as a minimum.  It might be better to have this moved to stackoverflow, more people might be able to help you.

Comment: did you know the esp can only do a couple hundred `analogRead()` commands in a second without crashing? plus, you send each sample, which is sure to drastically lower that 200Hz sample rate.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend to stream audio via ESP8266.
The maximum rate of reading the analog input is 200 per second.
This means, that you can play the audio at a maximum of 200Hz.
Usual .wav files are need a minimum (I would recommend) of 8000Hz.
Good quality is achievable at 44100Hz.
I tried the same aproach as you did and all i got out of my speakers, were higher and lower noises.